# Unused bytes by protobuf implementation (for limiter implementation)

Tags: protocols, protocol-buffers, delimiter, nanopb

I need to transfer data over a serial port. In order to ensure integrity of the data, I want a small envelope protocol around each protobuf message. I thought about the following:

1. message type (1 byte)
2. message size (2 bytes)
3. protobuf message (N bytes)
4. (checksum; optional)

The message type will mostly be a mapping between messages defined in proto files. However, if a message gets corrupted or some bytes are lost, the message size will not be correct and all subsequent bytes cannot be interpreted anymore. One way to solve this would be the introduction of limiters between messages, but for that I need to choose something that is not used by protobuf. Is there a byte sequence that is never used by any protobuf message?

I also thought about a different way.  If the master finds out that packages are corrupted, it should reset the communication to a clean start. For that I want the master to send a RESTART command to the slave. The slave should answer with an ACK and then start sending complete messages again. All bytes received between RESTART and ACK are to be discarded by the master. I want to encode ACK and RESTART as special messages. But with that approach I face the same problem: I need to find byte sequences for ACK and RESTART that are not used by any protobuf messages.

Maybe I am also taking the wrong approach - feel free to suggest other approaches to deal with lost bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a byte sequence that is never used by any protobuf message?

No; it is a binary serializer and can contain arbitrary binary payloads (especially in the `bytes` type). You cannot use sentinel values. Length prefix is fine (your "message size" header), and a checksum may be a pragmatic option. Alternatively, you could *impose* an artificial sentinel to follow each message (maybe a guid chosen per-connection as part of the initial handshake), and use that to double-check that everything looks correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The length prefix would work for me except for when transmission errors (added/missing bytes) occur. In this case, the binary stream would become uninterpretable, as I don't know where to continue parsing. Do you have tips how to handle this? A guid might a good idea, but especially at the beginning, the serial communication might be unreliable, making it hard to agree on a guid..

Comment: @MaxBeikirch in that case it could *probably* be hard-coded? but... I'm not experienced enough with serial comms to advise on the best way to avoid issues from unreliable sources - I can just advise on how the protobuf format is defined :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to help recover packet synchronization after a rare problem is to use synchronization words in the beginning of the message, and use the checksum to check for valid messages.

This means that you put a constant value, e.g. 0x12345678, before your message type field. Then if a message fails checksum check, you can recover by finding the next 0x12345678 in your data.

Even though that value could sometimes occur in the middle of the message, it doesn't matter much. The checksum check will very probably catch that there isn't a real message at that position, and you can search forwards until you find the next marker.